# How to pass an argument to a dependency in Ant Build Tool

Tags: ant

I'm creating a target in the build.xml file which depends on three other targets:

```
<target name="test" depends="target1,target2,target3">
  <echo message="Build Successful!"/>
</target>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to pass some argument to 'target2'. Can this be done in Ant? If so, how can I do it?
Any help is truly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand how `depends` works?

When you call target `test`, it will run the following targets:

- `target1`
- `target2`
- `target3`
- `test`

In that order. There's no way for target `test` to pass any arguments to `target2`.

You can pass properties to your `build.xml` script using the `-D` parameter:

```
$ ant -Dsource.version="1.5" compile
```

When your build script is executed, the property `source.version` will be set to 1.5.

Otherwise, look at [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) task as a way of passing arguments to particular routines.

By the way, if I had more information what you want, I could give you a better answer.